# Oracle SQL 11g: Creating a Histogram of Flags Grouped BY Subscriber ID and Date

Tags: sql, oracle

#### I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+--------------------+---------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
| DATA_SUBSCRIBER_ID | MONTHLY_CALENDAR_ID | F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 | F5 |
+--------------------+---------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
|            3699060 | 01/07/2015          |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
|            3699247 | 01/07/2015          |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |
|            3699342 | 01/08/2015          |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
|            3699380 | 01/08/2015          |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |
|            3699506 | 01/09/2015          |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |
|            3699526 | 01/09/2015          |  0 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |
+--------------------+---------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I want to do a query such that the new table looks like:

```
MONTHLY_CALENDAR_ID, SUM(F1+F2+F3+F4+F5), SUM(F1), SUM(F2), SUM(F3), SUM(F4), SUM(F5), USERS_WITH_0_FLAGS, USERS_WITH_1_FLAGS, USERS_WITH_2_FLAGS, USERS_WITH_3_FLAGS, USERS_WITH_4_FLAGS, USERS_WITH_5_FLAGS
+---+------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |     A      | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M |
+---+------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 01/07/2015 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 01/08/2015 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 01/09/2015 | 7 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
+---+------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Basically, I can do all of the columns with the `SUM`. But I would like to count each row and record how many flags they have for each month. Any ideas how to query this?

#### My attempts:

```
SELECT 
MONTHLY_CALENDAR_ID, 
SUM(F1 + F2 + F3 + F4 + F5 ), 
SUM(F1), SUM(F2), SUM(F3), SUM(F4), SUM(F5),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a WHERE SUM(F1 + F2 + F3 + F4 + F5 )) AS USERS_WITH_0_FLAGS
FROM ANA_SUB a GROUP BY MONTHLY_CALENDAR_ID ORDER BY MONTHLY_CALENDAR_ID;
```

Comment: Show us your attempt and we will help you where you are facing issue. Please don't expect us to give u the whole code.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I edited the question with my query attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first calculating the number of flags per user, using that to populate columns to indicate how many flags that user had (eg. if the user had 0 flags, populate the users_with_0_flags with 1 else 0, 1 flags, populate the users_with_1_flags with 1 else 0, etc) and then using that in the group by, like so:

```
WITH ana_sub AS (SELECT 3699060 data_subscriber_id, to_date('01/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') monthly_calendar_id, 0 f1, 1 f2, 0 f3, 0 f4, 0 f5 FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 3699247 data_subscriber_id, to_date('01/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') monthly_calendar_id, 0 f1, 0 f2, 1 f3, 1 f4, 0 f5 FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 3699342 data_subscriber_id, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') monthly_calendar_id, 0 f1, 0 f2, 0 f3, 0 f4, 0 f5 FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 3699380 data_subscriber_id, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') monthly_calendar_id, 1 f1, 0 f2, 0 f3, 0 f4, 1 f5 FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 3699506 data_subscriber_id, to_date('01/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') monthly_calendar_id, 1 f1, 1 f2, 1 f3, 0 f4, 0 f5 FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 3699526 data_subscriber_id, to_date('01/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') monthly_calendar_id, 0 f1, 1 f2, 1 f3, 1 f4, 1 f5 FROM dual),
    user_res AS (SELECT user_id,
                        monthly_calendar_id,
                        total_flags_per_user,
                        f1,
                        f2,
                        f3,
                        f4,
                        f5,
                        CASE WHEN total_flags_per_user = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END users_with_0_flags,
                        CASE WHEN total_flags_per_user = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END users_with_1_flags,
                        CASE WHEN total_flags_per_user = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END users_with_2_flags,
                        CASE WHEN total_flags_per_user = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END users_with_3_flags,
                        CASE WHEN total_flags_per_user = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END users_with_4_flags,
                        CASE WHEN total_flags_per_user = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END users_with_5_flags
                 FROM   (SELECT data_subscriber_id user_id,
                                monthly_calendar_id,
                                f1,
                                f2,
                                f3,
                                f4,
                                f5,
                                f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 + f5 total_flags_per_user
                         FROM   ana_sub))
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY monthly_calendar_id) rn,
       monthly_calendar_id a,
       sum(total_flags_per_user) b/*total_flags_per_month*/,
       SUM(f1) c/*f1_total*/,
       SUM(f2) d/*f2_total*/,
       SUM(f3) e/*f3_total*/,
       SUM(f4) f/*f4_total*/,
       SUM(f5) g/*f5_total*/,
       SUM(users_with_0_flags) h/*users_with_0_flags_total*/,
       SUM(users_with_1_flags) i/*users_with_1_flags_total*/,
       SUM(users_with_2_flags) j/*users_with_2_flags_total*/,
       SUM(users_with_3_flags) k/*users_with_3_flags_total*/,
       SUM(users_with_4_flags) l/*users_with_4_flags_total*/,
       SUM(users_with_5_flags) m/*users_with_5_flags_total*/
FROM   user_res
GROUP BY monthly_calendar_id;
```

which gives:

```
RN A           B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M
-- ---------- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 1 01/07/2015  3  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
 2 01/08/2015  2  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0
 3 01/09/2015  7  1  2  2  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0
```

N.B. I am assuming here that there is a unique or primary key on (data_subscriber_id, monthly_calendar_id)

Comment: There is a unique key on DATA_SUBSCRIBER_ID. For each ID, there is a list of 36 months. Thank you for your code. I will try it out right now.

Comment: If there are 36 months per data_subscriber_id, then data_subscriber_id can't be the unique key? Anyway, what I was trying to get at is that there's only one row possible for each data_subscriber_id and monthy_calendar_id combination. Which it sounds like is the case.